# Does Leveling Up Heal Unconscious Characters?

Tags: dnd-5e, hit-points, unconscious

A character in my group ran into a funny situation where his character fell unconscious but the other characters eliminated monsters, which caused them to level up. When a character levels up, they gain the new hit points added to their max.

My question is would the unconscious character gain these new hit points and gain consciousness?

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate. Let us know if the linked question doesn’t answer your question, and if not, why.

Comment: I just responded to that other question. I don't believe that is right. And if that's the case, then my question stands. See: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/178291/66043

Comment: @OneEye Even if you disagree with the accepted answer on the other question, that doesn't make the question not a duplicate.

Comment: Yes it does because that would make this a valid question. This technically isn't a duplicate question. It's just invalid if the other question means that characters don't gain HP at all on level up. If they do, however, then this question seems appropriate.